# Converting a simple hash function from c to go

Tags: c, go, hash

I'm trying to to convert a simple hash-function from C to Go.

What is the difference between these C and Go scripts and how do I fix the Go code?

C -> Results in {FB;01;4C|64:KDY;KMT;KYR;KT0;TKK;PAC;UD01;UD02;UD03;ID01;ID02;ID03;SYS|124A}

```
int   sum;
char* pChar;
char  s[8];

msg = "{FB;01;4C|64:KDY;KMT;KYR;KT0;TKK;PAC;UD01;UD02;UD03;ID01;ID02;ID03;SYS|"
sum = 0;
pChar = msg + 1; // sum starts after the opening {
while (*pChar != 0) {
  sum += (int)*pChar++;
}
sprintf(s, "%04X}", sum);
strcat(msg, s);
```

Go -> Results in {FB;01;4C|64:KDY;KMT;KYR;KT0;TKK;PAC;UD01;UD02;UD03;ID01;ID02;ID03;SYS|004A}

```
msg := "{FB;01;4C|64:KDY;KMT;KYR;KT0;TKK;PAC;UD01;UD02;UD03;ID01;ID02;ID03;SYS|"
var sum uint8
for i := 1; i < len(msg); i++ {
    sum += msg[i]
}
s := fmt.Sprintf("%04X}", sum)
req := strings.Join([]string{msg, s}, "")
fmt.Println(req)
```

Comment: `sum` in your C code has type `int`, which is at least a 16-bit signed integer (but more likely to be a 32-bit signed integer). In your Go code, you made `sum` an 8-bit unsigned integer (`uint8`). Also, if that's your actual C code, you're using `strcat` with a string literal as the first parameter, meaning it cannot be modified, so whatever program is using that piece of code will likely halt execution.

Comment: Excellent, please provide this as an answer. However, how can I convert that to bytes?

    invalid operation: sum += msg[i] (mismatched types uint32 and byte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C code, the type of `sum` is `int`, which is a signed integer type at least 16 bits in size<sup>1</sup>.

However, the type of `sum` is `uint8` in your Go code, an unsigned integer type limited to 8 bits.

Judging by your format string `%04X}`, you probably are wanting a 16-bit value.

To fix the Go code, just change `uint8` to `int` and use `sum += int(msg[i])` to make the compiler happy.  If you want to keep the value of `sum` strictly 16-bit, you could use `uint16` instead and `sum += uint16(msg[i])`.

If you're wondering why you need to wrap `msg[i]` in `uint16(...)`, it's because you're converting the value to a different type.  C has "integer promotion" rules that automatically convert a value that has a width less than `int` to a value of type `int`.  Go, however, has no such rules and simply refuses to compile, stating that the types are incompatible.

---

By the way, you could simply do this in your Go code due to its automatic memory management:

```
req := msg + fmt.Sprintf("%04X}", sum)
fmt.Println(req)
```

or even:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%04X}", sum)
fmt.Println(msg + sum)
```

Nothing wrong with your current approach; it's just extra verbose.

---

<sup>1</sup> `int` is required to be at least 16-bit in C and at least 32-bit in Go, but it is commonly 32-bit these days in both languages.  You should be aware, however, that it could be 64-bit on some current systems and could very well be 64-bit by default at some point in the future for either language; they're not required to keep their data type sizes synchronized.  You should keep this in mind when adding the values in `msg` to ensure the value of `sum` is 16-bit (or just use `uint16`).

Answer (score 4):

You need to make "var sum" an "uint16", otherwise it'll never go above 00FF.

Comment: thx, that's to the point. Chrono's answer was more detailed but you are perfectly right